# Google Analytics OAuth2 authorization using Java for a Service Account

Tags: java, oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In order for me to access Google analytics data, I am trying to build a Java program to just do the authentication and return me an access token. So I can use the access token in a datawarehouse tool and make HTTP calls to the Analytics API's. Since this is a server-server model, I created a Service account. But I'm not sure what classes/methods to use from the Google OAuth API's to make a request for the access token.

I am a new bee to Java and I am wondering how to figure that out.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloAnalytics {

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "C:/myfile.p12";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "mysrvcaccnt@gmail.com";


public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {

     //TokenRequest access_token = execute();
     Credential credential = getAccessToken();        
      System.out.println("return value " +credential);
      System.exit(0);
    } 
 catch (Exception e)    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static Credential getAccessToken()  throws Exception {
    // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.

    // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
    // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
        .build();
    credential.getAccessToken();
    return credential;

    // Construct the Analytics service object.
    //  return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    //    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show some of the code you've tried, otherwise it's going to be very difficult to help out! Also, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v1

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaap! I have added the code what I have so far to the original question. I am using the Credential class. But I think it just generates a refresh token.
What I'm trying is to generate a new access token.